# All magic comes with a price. Why "comes" not "come"?

Tags: present-simple

"Once Upon a Time" series character Rumpelstiltskin has catchphrase "All magic comes with a price". Is it grammatically correct? I know that magic can be countable or uncountable, but word "all" hints that its countable plural here, so it should be "come" not "comes". Or is purposely incorrect to mimic old English language?

Comment: "All" can be used with uncountable nouns. You might be confusing it with "every", which only applies to countable nouns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct.  This is the singular uncountable form magic, and "All" means "all of it" (not "all of them")

Magic is rarely countable, but if it is, then it has a regular plural "magics". So we know from the form alone that "magic" is not plural.